# CSS and parent/child, inherited attributes syntax and possibilities

Tags: html, css

I have this and it does everything I want it to, but it seems to me there would be a way to do this so that I can control the height of the divs seperately from all of the other identical properties. I just haven't been able through my searches to find a way that makes sense to me.

Note I am about 3 days into html so if this is over complicated I will learn in steps I understand. I understood style sheets to simplify the process so it seemed like there would be a simpler way.

Thanks

```
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {

        width:1240px;
        border:solid 1px black  
    }

    .rightline1{float:right;width:618px;height:80px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .rightline2{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .rightline3{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .rightline4{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .rightline5{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .rightline6{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .rightline7{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .rightline8{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .rightline9{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .rightline10{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .rightline11{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .rightline12{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .leftline1{float:left;width:618px;height:80px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .leftline2{float:left;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .leftline3{float:left;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .leftline4{float:left;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .leftline5{float:left;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .leftline6{float:left;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .leftline7{float:left;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .leftline8{float:left;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .leftline9{float:left;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .leftline10{float:left;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .leftline11{float:left;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
    .leftline12{float:left;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div class="leftline1"></div>
    <div class="rightline1"></div>
    <div class="leftline2"></div>
    <div class="rightline2"></div>
    <div class="leftline3"></div>
    <div class="rightline3"></div>
    <div class="leftline4"></div>
    <div class="rightline4"></div>
    <div class="leftline5"></div>
    <div class="rightline5"></div>
    <div class="leftline6"></div>
    <div class="rightline6"></div>
    <div class="leftline7"></div>
    <div class="rightline7"></div>
    <div class="leftline8"></div>
    <div class="rightline8"></div>
    <div class="leftline9"></div>
    <div class="rightline9"></div>
    <div class="leftline10"></div>
    <div class="rightline10"></div>
    <div class="leftline11"></div>
    <div class="rightline11"></div>
    <div class="leftline12"></div>
    <div class="rightline12"></div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Create a separate rule with all common styles, and apply to all classes, like this

   ```
   .rightline1, .rightline2 (...) .rightLine12 { /* all current rules here */ }
   ```

   And then just add a separate rule for a single class when necessary.
2. Another option (looks better to me): since you can assign any number of classes to an element, just add an extra class for the common styles. Example:

   HTML:

   ```
   <p class="rightline rightline1">Lorem ipsum</p>
   ```

   CSS:

   ```
   .rightline { /* all current rules here */ } 
   .rightline1 { width: 200px; }
   ```

Comment: ok first thank you for the amazing quick response and secondly i didnt know you could assign multiple classes to an element. Thanks again that answers all my questions right there.

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse CSS classes on more than one HTML element.  For example, these two CSS classes are exactly the same:

```
.rightline2{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
.rightline3{float:right;width:618px;height:20px;border:solid 1px black;}
```

so this class can be defined just once and used wherever you need it.

Example of class reuse (same CSS class used on two divs):

```
<div class="rightline2"></div>
<div class="rightline2"></div>
```

Comment: Yes and i am sorry i should have clarified better this build a layout of cells and i am going to resize each cell individually to creat the layout i need for the page thank you for response

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can write the same CSS like this:

```
body {
    width:1240px;
    border:solid 1px black  
}

.rightline1, .rightline2, .rightline3, .rightline4, .rightline5, .rightline6, .rightline7, .rightline8, .rightline9, .rightline10, .rightline11, .rightline12{
    float:right;
    width:618px;
    height:20px;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
.leftline1, .leftline2, .leftline3, .leftline4, .leftline5, .leftline6, .leftline7, .leftline8, .leftline9, .leftline10, .leftline11, .leftline12 {
    float:left;
    width:618px;
    height:20px;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
```

So that is a bit cleaner. But it sounds like you want to consolidate all of those rightlines and leftlines. So this would be better:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            width:1240px;
            border:solid 1px black  
        }

        .rightline, .leftline {
            width:618px;
            height:20px;
            border:solid 1px black;
        }

        .rightline {
            float:right;
        }
        .leftline {
            float:left;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div class="leftline"></div>
            <div class="rightline"></div>
            <div class="leftline"></div>
            <div class="rightline"></div>
            <div class="leftline"></div>
            <div class="rightline"></div>
            <div class="leftline"></div>
            <div class="rightline"></div>
            <div class="leftline"></div>
            <div class="rightline"></div>
            <div class="leftline"></div>
            <div class="rightline"></div>
            <div class="leftline"></div>
            <div class="rightline"></div>
            <div class="leftline"></div>
            <div class="rightline"></div>
            <div class="leftline"></div>
            <div class="rightline"></div>
            <div class="leftline"></div>
            <div class="rightline"></div>
            <div class="leftline"></div>
            <div class="rightline"></div>
            <div class="leftline"></div>
            <div class="rightline"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

In your original code you were using classes more like Ids. If you have something like `<div id='abc'></div>` then that means that there will not be (well, should not be) any other elements on the page with an id of `abc`. Ids are unique.

Classes, on the other hand, are used to identify groups of elements. So instead of giving each a unique class you should be giving them similar classes. In my last example I gave `.rightline` and `.leftline` shared styles. Since, except for the float direction, they are the same. Then I just give each their own float direction.

**EDIT** I updated the last example to have proper indents :)